# Responsive UI in async drawing

Tags: wpf, multithreading, drawing, propertychanged

I am trying to create a drawing with 5000 `Shape` objects in a background thread on a canvas.
I use the asyn-await pattern:

```
async void CreateDrawingAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => CreateDrawing()).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
void CreateDrawing()
{
    DrawObjects = new ObservableCollectionEx<DrawObject>();
    // or: DrawObjects.Clear();
    RaisePropertyChanged("DrawObjects");
    // etc ... etc ...
}
```

`ObservableCollectionEx` means I use an extension of `ObservableCollection` to add an object to the collection via the Dispatcher.
When I start `CreateDrawingAsync` in the Loaded event of the Window (in the ctor of `Data`) the UI is unresponsive.
Using DispatcherPriority.Background the items are added one by one in the UI, but also in that case, the UI is unresponsive.

```
Loaded += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
{
     DataContext = new Data(2000, 1000, 1000);
};
```

1) I expected the background thread would resolve the unresponsive UI issue, what am I overlooking?

2) Why does `RaisePropertyChanged("DrawObjects")` (see code above) have no effect? I would have expected the drawing would be cleared due to the propertychanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do UI operations on a background thread. This includes:

- Drawing on a canvas.
- Raising `PropertyChanged` notifications.
- Creating or updating an `ObservableCollection`.

Creating a fake-UI component like `ObservableCollectionEx` that just forwards all its work to the UI thread doesn't gain you anything.

Comment: Thanks for answering, and the answer is very clear... But really, isn't there any way to get a responsive UI while drawing?

Comment: Using `DispatcherPriority.Background` the items are added one by one, but also in that case, the UI is unresponsive.